# How to check the key of a specific string from a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm making a small game of questions and answers in which, to find out what is the correct answer I have thought about using a dictionary, to check with a key and a 'if' statement the correct answer. The code is the following, but basically I take the answers from a SQLite database, then I put them in a dictionary, which is converted into a list, I shuffled it and put each component of the list in a text to show them in differents UI buttons. Here it is:

```
string A_p = reader.GetString(3);
string B_p = reader.GetString(4);
string C_p = reader.GetString(5);
string D_p = reader.GetString(6);





Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryAnswers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionaryAnswers[A_p] = "C";
dictionaryAnswers[B_p] = "W";
dictionaryAnswers[C_p] = "W";
dictionaryAnswers[D_p] = "W";                       
listAnswers = dictionaryAnswers.Keys.ToList();

var randomizer = new System.Random();
for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryAnswers.Count / 2; i++)
{
    var randNum = randomizer.Next(i, listAnswers.Count);
    var temp = listAnswers[randNum];
    listAnswers[randNum] = listAnswers[i];
    listAnswers[i] = temp;
}

string A = listAnswers.First();
listAnswers.Remove(A);
string B = listAnswers.First();
listAnswers.Remove(B);
string C = listAnswers.First();
listAnswers.Remove(C);
string D = listAnswers.First();
listAnswers.Remove(D);





QuestionText.text = question;
AnswerAText.text = A;
AnswerBText.text = B;
AnswerCText.text = C;
AnswerDText.text = D;
```

If the code is not undestandable, please let me know. The thing is, I don't know how to check what of this strings (A, B, C, D) contains the key that I am looking for. Can someone, please, guide me on how to do what I intend. Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dictionaryAnswers)
{
    Debug.Log(item.Key);
    Debug.Log(item.Value);
}
```